# TikZ: xshift not shifting

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why wont `xshift` work here?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (Q) at (2.1cm, -1cm);

  \draw[xshift = 0.5cm] (Q) -- +(0, 3cm); % no shift

  \begin{scope}[xshift = 0.5cm]
    \draw (Q) -- +(0, 3cm); % no shift
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both the scoped and non-scoped version produce the same image:

[image]

As we can see, the line is drawn from `Q` and not shifted.

Comment: `\draw (Q) ++(0.5cm,0) -- +(0,3cm);`

Comment: @JLDiaz so `xshift` wont or can't work in this case?

Comment: Apparently named nodes cannot be shifted. Their names make them somewhat "absolute"

Comment: @JLDiaz do you want to make an answer?  I used your comment to solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, I elaborated it a bit

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As explained in another answer, named nodes are somewhat "absolute" coordinates, and they are not affected by standard transforms (shift, rotate, scale, etc.) They can be transformed via a `transform canvas`, however, but this is generally discouraged, specially for scale changes, because it affects also to the size and aspect of strokes, fonts, etc.

So, leaving shifts alone, which alternatives do we have?

1. Use `calc` to manually add some amount to each coordinate, e.g: `($(Q)+(0.5, 0)$)`
2. Use `++` syntax to set a new "origin" and `+` syntax to specify coordinates relative to that origin.

Using the second approach for this particular case:

```
\draw (Q) ++(0.5, 0) -- +(0,3);
```

which means:

1. Go to coordinate `(Q)`
2. Move `(0.5,0)` from that coordinate and set this new point as origin for relative coordinates
3. Draw a line from the last point to the one which is at `(0,3)` from it.

Comment: How can I move later on (not only at start?) `\draw (Q) ++(0.5, 0) -- (P) +(0,3);` to say "make line to P + (0,3)" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb For this case the first option is the way to go, i.e. `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`and the syntax: `\draw ($(Q)+(0.5,0)$) -- ($(P)+(0,3)$);`

Answer (score 25):

AFAIK named coordinates survive a transformation unchanged unless the canvas is transformed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (Q) at (2.1cm, -1cm);
  \draw (Q) -- +(0, 3cm);

  \draw[transform canvas={xshift = 0.5cm}] (Q) -- +(0, 3cm);

  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift = 1cm}]
    \draw (Q) -- +(0, 3cm);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

You can `shift` named coordinates if you apply `shift` to each coordinate, not to the whole scope:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (Q) at (2.1cm, -1cm);

  \draw[xshift = 0.5cm] (Q) -- +(0, 3cm) node[midway, above,sloped] {no shift};

  \draw[red] ([xshift = 0.5cm]Q) -- +(0, 3cm) node[midway, above,sloped] {shifted}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Putting ([xshift=0.5] Q) definetly does not work with Tikz 3.0. It was the first (logical) thing I tried. It is according to the syntax to shift a single coordinate.

Comment: @jlinkels In this case `Q` is a `coordinate` and `([xshift=0.5]Q)` works perfectly. If `Q` is a `node` you need to use `([xshift=0.5]Q.center)`.

Comment: @jlinkels If you downvoted for this (yours) mistake, I think you could reconsider your vote. In any case, I think it's more polite to claim my attention with a comment and wait some time for an answer before downvote.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Both on syntax and commenting first before downvoting. My apologies. It works on a coordinate like you say. It does NOT work on this: \draw ([xshift=0.5] A1.left) but it does on ([xshift=0.5] A1.center). Which is nice nut useless, because you can't offset anything to the side of a node, which sometimes is needed. I would like to undo the downvote, but I cannot until your answer has been edited.

Comment: And to complete on the application of a shift to a node coordinate, this a way to apply an offset: \draw  (R1.east) ++(0,0.1)  -- (2,2)

Comment: @jlinkels `\draw([xshift=0.5]A1.left)` doesn't work because `.left` is not an `anchor` is a relative position. When you say `left=... of ...` the new position is relative to `west` anchor. `\draw([xshift=0.5]A1.west)` will work.