# shift not works when coordinate is used

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In tikz, if I use the the absolute coordinates of the point, the `shift` key works well and the object is moved by the `shift`, but I use the the command `\coordinate` to store the point, 
the `shift` key doesn't work. I wonder why this happen.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \draw (a)--(0,1);
        \draw[xshift=2cm] (0,0)--+(0,1);% works;
        % \draw[xshift=2cm] (a)--+(0,1);% not works
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The following would be one way : `\draw ([xshift=2cm]a)--+(0,1);`

Comment: [Another solution, from Heiko Oberdiek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180669/116936) : `\draw[transform canvas={xshift = 2cm}] (a) -- +(0,1);`

Comment: @marsupilam Thanks for your comments. They solve my problem :-)