# How to draw these images with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I had once the need to use these graphics:
[image: first one]
[image: second one]

It seemed to be a simple table, but I was not able to

- draw randomly while crossing table lines, but with respect to the cell's coordinates (like in the first picture)
- set an offset to distinguish the continuous line from the dotted line (second picture)

I do not have to use these graphics now, but I found that it annoyed me not knowing how to do this.
I am sure one could draw them completely within TikZ, but perhaps it is possible to marry TikZ with a table to not being bothered with a complicated calculation of coordinates.

Could anyone give a hint or a solution? My TikZ knowledge is rather small and merely of theoretical nature.

Comment: Doing everything in TikZ is probably less fuzz than mixing in a `tabular`, a TikZ `\matrix` might be useful. As an addendum, I know the following isn't that helpful, but at a basic level the diagrams are quite simple. If you know how to draw a line between points and how to place text at a specified point, you can do the bulk of them, so a lot of TikZ knowledge isn't needed. (Of course, some knowledge could make it easier to do.)

Comment: The first picture can be obtained e.g. with `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (-2,1) -- (4.5,1) (-1,2) -- (-1,-4.5);
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {\mu=0,1,2,3,\cdots}
 {\node[above=0.5ex] at (\Y,1) {$\X$};}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {\nu=0,1,2,3,\cdots}
 {\node[left=0.5ex] at (-1,-\Y) {$\X$};}
 \draw[mark=*] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (2,-1) (3,-1) (3,-2) (4,-2)
 (4,-3)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` ...

Comment: It's wonderful to now have two different approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one possibility using a `\matrix`. There are some comments in the code, ask if anything is unclear.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

% hack for style of empty cells from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386805/ 
\tikzset{empty node/.style={coordinate}}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,empty node]{};\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix [
  % with the following option each cell becomes a node, set in math mode
   % the nodes are named automatically as <matrix name>-<row number>-<column number>
   matrix of math nodes, 
   nodes in empty cells, % add cells also to empty nodes
   nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, font=\strut} % set style of nodes
] (m) % give the matrix the name m
{
 & \mu = 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots \\
\nu = 0 & & & & & \\
1 & & & & & \\
2 & & & & & \\
3 & & & & & \\
\vdots & & & & &  \\
};

% for explanation of |- syntax: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/
% used to ensure horizontal/vertical lines
\draw (m-1-2.north west) -- (m-1-2.north west |- m-6-1.south east);
\draw (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.north west -| m-1-6.south east);

% due to the automatic node naming mentioned above, m-1-2 is the
% node in the first row, second column of the matrix

% a plot is an easy way of drawing a line with dots
\draw plot[mark=*] coordinates {(m-2-2)(m-2-3)(m-2-4)(m-3-4)(m-3-5)};


% for explanation of |- syntax: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/
% using that you only need to specify every other corner on the path
\draw (m-3-2) |- (m-4-3) |- (m-6-6);

% draw shifted, dotted line
% transform canvas idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180669/ 
\draw [dotted, transform canvas={shift={(5pt,5pt)}}] (m-3-2) |- (m-4-3) |- (m-6-6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I did not even know that a matrix could have this kind of arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz to draw the broken lines with the Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceArray}{c|ccccc}
           & \mu = 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots \\
   \hline
   \nu = 0 \\
   1       \\
   2       \\
   3       \\
   \vdots  
\CodeAfter
   \tikz [radius=2pt,every circle/.style = fill]
    \draw plot [mark = *] coordinates 
      {(2.5-|2.5)(2.5-|3.5)(2.5-|4.5)(3.5-|4.5)(3.5-|5.5)(4.5-|5.5)(4.5-|6.5)(5.5-|6.5)} ;
\end{NiceArray}
\]


\[
\begin{NiceArray}{c|ccccccc}
          & \mu = 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \hline
  \nu = 0 \\
  1       \\
  2       \\
  \cdot   \\
  \cdot   \\
  \cdot   \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2.5-|2.5) -- (2.5-|4.5) |- (3.5-|5.5) |- (4.5-|6.5) |- (5.5-|7.5) ; 
    \draw (2.5-|2.5) -- (5.5-|2.5) -| (6.5-|3.5) -| (7.5-|4.5) ; 
    \draw [dotted] 
          ([xshift=1mm]2.5-|2.5) |- (3.5-|3.5) |- (4.5-|4.5) |- (5.5-|5.5) |- (6.5-|6.5) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]