Conflict between scope shift en node positioning
I am faced with an issue, ChatGPT and I can't seem to solve so here I am.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning} % pour le positionnement relatif
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

 \newcommand{\ABSwitch}[4]{
    \coordinate (A0) at #1;
    \node at (A0) {#2};
    \path (A0)-- ++(DiagShift) -- ++($-1*(ABShift)$)  node[anchor=center] {#3};
    \path (A0)-- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center] {#4};
 }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\Largeur{3}
        \def\Hauteur{2}
        \coordinate (ABShift) at (.85,-1.4);
        \coordinate (DiagShift) at (\Largeur,-\Hauteur);
        \begin{scope}
            \ABSwitch{(0,0)}{A1}{B1}{C1}
            \ABSwitch{(0,-2)}{A2}{B2}{C2}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm] 
            \ABSwitch{(0,-5)}{A3}{B3}{C3}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Gives :

And you can see all the placement but C3 are working fine.
Any idea on why that is ? And how to fix it ?
Thank you in advance
To be exact I did find a fix using :
\def\ABShift{.85,-1.4}
\def\DiagShift{\Largeur,-\Hauteur}

But I would like to be able to use positioning without having to patch by hand.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} very likely not needed.

See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180665/47927 ; TL;DR a scoped xshift has no effect on coordinates.

@JasperHabicht Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't provide a satisfactory explanation as to why only C3 is misplaced.

Well, the path for the second node has ($-1*(ABShift)$), so the xshift is cancelled out here which is why only the third node is misplaced.

@JasperHabicht Thank you again, but the line containing the code you're referring to is the one placing Bs and the misplaced node is a C. And I don't know what you mean by cancelled, because I tried making a copy of the line you're talking about and le second copy didn't seem affected and worked well. I also tried removing the line concerning the Bs and the Cs were unaffected, still misplaced.

It is a bit difficult to see this here, but in general, a shift transformation applied on a scope does not affect coordinates. See: TikZ: xshift not shifting.
Now, in your example this statement is directly visible when looking at C3, but not so much when looking at B3 which actually seems to be affected by the shift transformation.
Let us look into your example. I modified it a bit to make things a bit easier to see.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (ABShift) at (.85,-1.4);
        \coordinate (DiagShift) at (3,-2);
    
        \begin{scope}
            \coordinate (A0) at (0,0) node {A1};
            \draw[black!50, thick] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, black] {B1a};
            \draw[black!25] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++($-1*(ABShift)$) node[anchor=center, black] {B1};
            \draw[black!25, dashed] (A0) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, black] {C1};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm] 
            \coordinate (A0) at (0,0) node[red] {A2};
            \draw[thick, red!25] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, red] {B2a};
            \draw[red!50] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++($-1*(ABShift)$) node[anchor=center, red] {B2};
            \draw[red!50, dashed] (A0) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, red] {C2};
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As can be seen, A1, B1, B1a and C1 are in a non-shifted scope (drawn in black) and A2, B2, B2a and C2 are in a shifted scope (drawn in red). It is easy to see that coordinate C1 and C2 sit on the same position although one of them is in a shifted scope. It is also easy to see that ++(DiagShift) results in the very same coordinate, regardless whether being in a shifted scope or not. This is probably a bit counterintuitive, because (DiagShift) is not exactly added to (A0) here.
Now, you use a factor of -1 with which you invert (ABShift) before you add this coordinate to (A0) ++(DiagShift). Looking at the picture above, you can see the position of B1a and B2a that show the non-inverted position of (A0) ++(DiagShift) ++(ABShift) and you can see that this is pretty much the same as (A0) ++(ABShift) (that is, C1 and C2), but shifted by (DiagShift), of course.
But here you can also see that the position of (A0) ++(DiagShift) ++(ABShift) in the shifted scope relative to the non-shifted scope is xshift=-3cm (the reverse of the shift applied to the scope). And also, if you have (A0) ++(DiagShift) ++($-1*(ABShift)$), you reach the same position as if you would have applied xshift=3cm because of the different position of (A0) relative to the fixed coordinates which differs by xshift=3cm.

Since it seems that you want to define the coodinates using some \defs anyways, a simple solution would be to define the coorinates inside the scope:
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\ABShiftX{.85}
        \def\ABShiftY{-1.4}
        \def\DiagShiftX{3}
        \def\DiagShiftY{-2}
    
        \begin{scope}
            \coordinate (A0) at (0,0) node {A1};
            \coordinate (DiagShift) at (\DiagShiftX,\DiagShiftY);
            \coordinate (ABShift) at (\ABShiftX,\ABShiftY);
            \draw[black!50, thick] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, black] {B1a};
            \draw[black!25] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++($-1*(ABShift)$) node[anchor=center, black] {B1};
            \draw[black!25, dashed] (A0) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, black] {C1};
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm] 
            \coordinate (A0) at (0,0) node[red] {A2};
            \coordinate (DiagShift) at (\DiagShiftX,\DiagShiftY);
            \coordinate (ABShift) at (\ABShiftX,\ABShiftY);
            \draw[thick, red!25] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, red] {B2a};
            \draw[red!50] (A0) -- ++(DiagShift) -- ++($-1*(ABShift)$) node[anchor=center, red] {B2};
            \draw[red!50, dashed] (A0) -- ++(ABShift) node[anchor=center, red] {C2};
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for taking some time to answer me. So if I understand well, my B3 point was well placed only because the -1 was compensating the absence of shift. Now is there a way to do this scope shift correctly, impacting everything inside. Please don't tell me the only way is to shift every line. Latex can't be so disappointing...

Also I think you "a"s have disappeared from your B1a and B2a

@LMT-PhD Well, what could work is to define the coordinates inside the scope …

@LMT-PhD I edited my answer and provided a possible solution. Thanks for the notice of the missing "a"s!
